# C, printf loop and line change

Tags: c, arrays

I am new at C programming.

I have a 1-d array (size of array given by user, **containing seat numbers)**

I want to print the result in the screen but divide the results in MULTIPLE rows. Each row should have only 4 elements of the array, and the last one more elements.

Probably I will use a for loop combined with `printf` but can't think of the way to combine them.

So what I have tried and works but is not so elegant is this code, but I will have to repeat it about 15 times.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (seatnr[i] = 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
        if (seatnr[i] = 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
        if (seatnr[i] = 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did, or didn't that work? For your attempt, what is the actual output? And please *show* the expected output from your program (for some specified input). Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Plenty of ideas. But asking for ideas doesn't fit SOs Q&A format. So try something, and narrow down your question.

Comment: Whenever you need to repeat some part of your code, copy-paste is seldom the answer, but loops are. You can have nested loops, do it all in one well-crafted loop, a loop which calls a function which contains a loop (a variant of the nested loops), and many more ways.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j+=4)
{
     for (i=j; i < j+4; i++)
     {
         if (seatnr[i]==1) printf("1");
         else printf("0");
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Please fix the bug in `seatnr[i]=1`